# Strange values when dropping column from a supervised learning dataset

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, supervised-learning

I am trying to predict bike availability. Initially I've defined this problem as a time series. To predict the bikes I'm transforming my set to a supervised learning problem and then feeding it to the NN.

On a first approach the supervised problem I defined it as the following

`day_of_year(t-1) | time(t-1) | weekday(t-1) | weekday(t-1) | free_bikes(t-1) | free_bikes(t)`

But after thinking for a while. In the future when I want to predict bikes for the future, not near future, I'd like to know the availability for example the next day or next week  so I don't want to feed all the time-steps to the nn. Instead I've come up with this:

`day_of_year(t-1) | time(t-1) | weekday(t-1) | weekday(t-1) | free_bikes(t)`

I have removed `free_bikes(t-1)` as an input to the problem.

After this the predicted values are messed up, the predicted values are absurdly incorrect and I don't fully understand why is so.

Links:

- [Predicted values](https://imgur.com/a/hdRIG)
- [Output of the script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/716c7a1dd066269f25f9677c422a79e5)
- [Model](https://imgur.com/a/uw6Jz)

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, if you change the input dimensions, you need to retrain the model.

Your model has a input dimension of (batch_size,1,3). So it is one timestep and three features per time step. This doesnt match the input dimensions you described in your question.

Please specify the problem setup.